# How to show all values in arraylist android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have one function who check if emails in `Array` are correct or not. If emails are valid `return true` and send emails to server.

My problem comes when emails are invalid. I put every email in `ArrayList` and show them in `AlertDialog`. But in `AlerDialog` only one invalid email is shown because `return false`.
I tried to move this return but everything comes wrong.

I want to go trough `Array` with `loop` and when `loop` ends then it should `return false` and show `ArrayList`(I think this should  do the job ), but when I move `return false` after the `loop`, `AlertDialog` didn't work

This is my function

```
boolean checkedMails(String[] mails) {      
    for (int i = 0; i < mails.length; i++) {        
        if (!isEmailValid(mails[i])) {
            wrongEmails.add(mails[i]);
            Log.d("WRONGEMAILS", wrongEmails.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here i send emails or show alerDialog

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String IRegEmail = waitingForAdd.getText().toString();

                String[] mails = getAnswers();
                try {
                    if (checkedMails(mails)) {
                        sendEmails(mails);
                    } else {

                        alertDialogThis = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                ReferFriend.this);
                        timer = new Timer();
                        alertDialogThis.setMessage("Wrong emails are:"
                                + wrongEmails);
                        dlg = alertDialogThis.create();
                        dlg.show();
                        // dialog.dismiss();
                        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                dlg.dismiss();

                                timer.cancel();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                        wrongEmails.clear();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please add e-mails", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just set a boolean variable before the loop, and return it when the check is done.

```
boolean checkedMails(String[] mails) {

    boolean isGood = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < mails.length; i++) {


        if (!isEmailValid(mails[i])) {

            wrongEmails.add(mails[i]);
            Log.d("WRONGEMAILS", wrongEmails.toString());
            isGood = false;
        }


    }
    return isGood;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Only 1 email is showing because after the first invalid email, the function returns. I think this should help, add an additional flag for keeping track if the whole set is valid/invalid.

```
boolean checkedMails(String[] mails) {
        boolean isValid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < mails.length; i++) {
            if (!isEmailValid(mails[i])) {
                wrongEmails.add(mails[i]);
                Log.d("WRONGEMAILS", wrongEmails.toString());
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Comment: Ha! glad to see we were on the same page... posted less then a minute after this.